# Hacking WPA/WPA2 passwords

Tags: network, password-cracking, wpa2

Is there another method apart from using a wordlist to crack WPA/WPA2 passwords? because it's not going to work for all cases. Even using the biggest wordlist ever, there are cases where there won't be a match in the wordlist. (assuming that WPS is off too because if WPS is on, the password may be cracked through weaknesses of WPS)

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, there are other sorts of brute force attacks to crack passwords!

For example, on [Hashcat's website](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) you can find the following types of attacks:

- Straight *
- Combination
- Brute-force
- Hybrid dict + mask
- Hybrid mask + dict

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole class of key-reinstallation attacks discovered a few years ago, that doesn't rely on the traditional wordlist brute-forcing attacks. They are also known as KRACK - Key Reinstallation AttaCKs.

You can read more about such attacks [here](https://www.krackattacks.com/). After some initial publicity, though, many vendors' Wi-Fi products have been patched against at least some variations of KRACK.